# ASP.NET Core EF Query ignoring OrderBy when using Skip/Take with Subquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been running into problems with my application using asp.net core 1.1 and mvc. As best as I can tell, I'm getting incorrect results when performing a query, when combining orderby, skip/take, and a query on an included table.

The schema is pretty straight forward.

```
public Class Member
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Family {get; set;}
    public bool IsMember {get; set;}
    public DateTime DeceasedDate {get; set;}
    ...
    public int LivesWithId {get; set;}
    public Member LivesWith {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Member> LivingWith {get; set;}
}
```

The short of it is, is you have one person with a family, and other people can be set to live with this person. A standard one to many.

The c# code I'm running looks relatively simple... it finds anyone that is either a member or has someone living with them that isn't deceased. It's not a very good query, and it's kind of slow, but for my purposes it should be good enough. And it does work, until I toss in skip/take.

```
var q = _context.Members.Include(m => m.LivingWith).AsQueryable();

q = q.Where(m => m.IsMember || m.LivingWith.Count(s => s.DeceasedDate == null) > 0);
q = q.OrderBy(m => m.Family);
q = q.Skip(100);
q = q.Take(100);

var result = await q.ToListAsync();
```

Entity Framework takes this and spits out two queries. I'm not entirely sure why this is, the first query I think has everything that is needed... but the important thing is that entity framework appears to abandon the ordering, and I can't figure out why. Here's the SQL that is generated by this:

```
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Family], (...some fields omitted...)
FROM (
    SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Family], (...some fields omitted...) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [m].[Family]) AS [__RowNumber__]
    FROM [Members] AS [m]
    WHERE  (([m].[IsMember] = 1) OR ((
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Members] AS [s]
        WHERE [s].[DeceasedDate] IS NULL AND ([m].[Id] = [s].[LivesWithId])
    ) > 0))
) AS [t]
WHERE ([t].[__RowNumber__] > @__p_0) AND ([t].[__RowNumber__] <= (@__p_0 + @__p_1))
ORDER BY [t].[Id]

SELECT [m0].[Id], [m0].[Family], (...some fields omitted...)
FROM [Members] AS [m0]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[Family], (...some fields omitted...), ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [m].[Family]) AS [__RowNumber__]
        FROM [Members] AS [m]
        WHERE ([m].[IsMember] = 1) OR ((
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM [Members] AS [s]
            WHERE [s].[DeceasedDate] IS NULL AND ([m].[Id] = [s].[LivesWithId])
        ) > 0)
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE (([t].[__RowNumber__] > @__p_0) AND ([t].[__RowNumber__] <= (@__p_0 + @__p_1))) AND ([m0].[LivesWithId] = [t].[Id]))
ORDER BY [m0].[LivesWithId]
```

It may not be obvious, but entity framework is doing some funny business that breaks the order specified. It's splitting groups correctly with skip/take, but it's not sorting results within that group because it's tossing in the orderby id at the end. I'm not entirely sure if entity framework is doing something wrong, of if I am. I imagine my query might not be very good, but I had difficulty making a query where it wouldn't execute a separate query for each resulting row.

**Edit**: In the comments, it appears to be caused by a EF bug. For now, I can work around the issue by putting a second order by after the skip/take

Comment: I'm not sure, try changing `q = q.Where(m => m.IsMember || m.LivingWith.Count(s => s.DeceasedDate == null) > 0);` to `q = q.Where(m => m.IsMember || m.LivingWith.Where(s => s.DeceasedDate == null).Count() > 0);`

Comment: @doddler on an unrelated note dont use count use any
m.LivingWith.Any(s => s.DeceasedDate != null)

Comment: @johnny5 that's right, I forgot about the `Any`. I'd use `Where().Count()` if I had to check anything else, like `Count() > 10`. If I remember well, We can't use `Count()` overload with `lambda` because it'll defer the SQL execution. That's a shot, though...

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact code? Why are there two SQL statements is that generated from a single call.  I have a feeling you're omitting some stuff from the C# Code. Or alternatively everything is ordered by FamilyId and there are just multiple members belonging to that family

Comment: @johnny5: The c# code strangely exactly as is. The SQL executes as two separate calls based on the logs. I will use Any in the future, since the SQL does look a bit better, though it still suffers the same sorting issue. One thing I did notice is that I *can* get correct ordering if I use a second OrderBy after the take. It makes the SQL generated even weirder, but the result is right. But that seems pretty weird though...

Comment: I just can't imagine that EF would have a bug like that can you post the example of the results

Comment: @johnny5 I made a slimmed down test case, to try to rule out issues on [github](https://github.com/Doddler/EFQueryTest/tree/master/src/EFTestProject). The query is in the DefaultController, almost just as posted here. The results are completely unsorted though, the sample prints just the Family, which is what it's sorting on, and the results are "215, 130, 192, 166..." etc.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6736. Its a bug which has been fixed and will be available in next release.

Comment: @Smit Good find, I couldn't find it by looking, but my search skills seem to be lacking. That appears to be exactly the issue. For now, I appear to be able to work around the issue by having two orderby commands, one before and one after the skip/take. I'd mark this as solved, but not much I can do since it was solved in comments.